# SQL Exclude Row if Specific Value Exists Within Joined Field

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to write an SQL query that will allow me to exclude a record from TableA if it has at least one match against TableB.

I have written some code, as below, that almost gets me what I need -

```
SELECT a.ID,
  a.OPEN_DT,
  b.LINKCREATED,
  b.RULE__ID
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
  ON a.ROW_WID = b.A_ROW_WID
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.OPEN_DT) >= '2013'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM TableB
                  WHERE A_ROW_WID = a.ROW_WID
                  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM b.CREATED) >= '2017')
;
```

*Table A*

```
ROW_WID   |   ID   |   OPEN_DT
---------------------------------
1         |    A   |  2013-01-01
2         |    B   |  2014-01-01
3         |    C   |  2017-01-01
```

*Table B*

```
RULE_ID   |   A_ROW_WID   |   LINKCREATED   
---------------------------------
1         |    A          |   2014-01-01
2         |    A          |   2017-01-01
3         |    B          |   2017-01-01
```

The query above would return 1 row for ROW_WID = 1, 1 row for ROW_WID = 2 and nothing for ROW_WID = 3.

I would like my query to exclude ROW_WID=1 altogether because there is one row in TableB that has the year 2017.

I hope this question is clear, but let me know if not.

**-EDIT-**

Expected result would look like this -

```
   ID   |   OPEN_DT   |   LINKCREATED   |   RULE_ID
   C    |  2017-01-01 |   NULL          |   NULL
```

As ID 'C' from TableA has no link in TableB.

If there were an entry in A that had any links in B prior to 2017, they would be returned.  Just not any with a TableB entry >= 2017.

Comment: Try using `INNER JOIN`. The result would include ONLY those records that find a match at both sides.

Comment: Thank you, but the INNER JOIN will still return a result for ROW_WID=1 as I haven't been able to exclude the 1st row in TableB.

Comment: Can you include a code block example of what output you would want to get from your example tables?

Comment: Please show expected results in table form

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you aren't checking for the max created date in the NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT a.ID,
  a.OPEN_DT,
  b.LINKCREATED,
  b.RULE__ID
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
  ON a.ROW_WID = b.A_ROW_WID
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.OPEN_DT) >= '2013'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'NE'
                  FROM TableB B2
                  WHERE A_ROW_WID = a.ROW_WID
                  AND B2.LINKCREATED= (SELECT MAX(BE.LINKCREATED) FROM TableB BE WHERE B2.A_ROW_WID=BE.A_ROW_WID)
                  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM b2.CREATED) >= '2017')
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted but it actually appears to work.  I'll give it a full test to make sure then hopefully give it a big tick.

Answer (score 0):

Try using not in:

```
SELECT a.ID,
  a.OPEN_DT,
  b.LINKCREATED,
  b.RULE__ID
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
  ON a.ROW_WID = b.A_ROW_WID
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.OPEN_DT) >= '2013'
  AND b.rule_id not in (select rule_id from TableB where A_ROW_WID in (SELECT 
                  A_ROW_WID 
                  FROM TableB
                  WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM b.CREATED) >= '2017')a)b
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, but this still returns a row for ID 'A', which I would like to exclude.